# Prevent items in scope from writing to a different user's records

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I was having success with using AngularFire in a scenario where there is one user on my application.

Now that I have authentication up and running, I'm noticing that assigning `items` to `$scope.items` is catastrophic when switching users, mainly due to the `$scope` failing to update correctly.

Reading directly from the docs...

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/items');
angularFire(ref, $scope, 'items');
```

I need these to be only the `items` of the currently authorized user. So currently, I do this (if there's a better way, don't hesitate to tell me!)

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/items/userId');
angularFire(ref, $scope, 'items');
```

I generate `userId` using `auth.provider` and `auth.id`, btw. Now that my items are namespaced in (let's say) `user1`

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/items/[user1id]');
angularFire(ref, $scope, 'items');
```

I add items to `$scope.items`

```
$scope.create = function(item) {

  $scope.items.push(item)
  /* Pretend the user adds these from the interface.
  [
    { name: 'eenie' },
    { name: 'meenie' },
    { name: 'miney' },
    { name: 'moe' }
  ]
  */

}
```

**The problem**

Now if I just log out and login as someone else, magically that user has `eenie meenie miney` and `moe` because `$scope.items` held the array between logout and login.

I tried to set `$scope.items = []` on logout event, but that actually empties all the records. I'm pulling my hair out. This is 0.001% of what I need to do in my project and it's taking my whole weekend.

**Update** New method

```
  $scope.create = function() {
    $scope.selectedDevice = {
      name: 'New Device',
      userId: $scope.user.provider + $scope.user.id
    };
    return $scope.devices.push($scope.selectedDevice);
  };

  $scope.$on('angularFireAuth:login', function(evt, user) {
    var promise, ref;
    ref = new Firebase('https://mysite.firebaseio.com/users/' + (user.provider + user.id) + '/registry/');
    promise = angularFire(ref, $scope, 'devices');
  });
```

It now will accurately create items under the user's id. However, still, once you logout and log back in, those items do not get cleared from `$scope.devices`. Therefore, they just add themselves to data but under the newly logged in user.

**Update**

I did a lot of trial and error. I probably set `$scope.devices` to `[]` and moved around login events in every possible combination. What eventually worked was @hiattp's fiddle in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of the implicit data binding remaining intact as you switch users. If the new user shows up and creates a new binding, it will consider the existing data to be local changes that it should assimilate (that's why you see the original user's items being added to the new user), but if you try to clear them first without releasing the binding then you are implicitly telling Firebase to delete that data from the original user's item list (also not what you want). So you need to release the data bindings when you detect the logout (or login) events as needed.

The callback in the `angularFire` promise provides an "unbind" method (see [here](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/59#issuecomment-20891312) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/pull/34)):

```
var promise = angularFire(ref, $scope, 'items');
promise.then(function(unbind){
  // Calling unbind() will disassociate $scope.items from Firebase
  // and generally it's useful to add unbind to the $scope for future use.
});
```

You have a few idiosyncrasies in your code that are likely causing it not to work, and remember that `unbind` won't clear the local collection for you. But just so you have an idea of how it *should* work (and to prove it *does* work) here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWkaX/2/).

Comment: No, that isn't really there. I'm just showing what it might look like. I'll clarify above. There would not actually be any literal definition.

Comment: I tried what you have above, but I'm afraid this does not solve the problem. Items from the previously logged-in user simply add themselves to the new one. I'll post new code above.

Comment: Gotcha yeah that static array threw me off. I updated the answer, that should help.

Comment: I also tried your second link, but it also did not solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to do that. It's crazy mine is not working that way. There must be something else mucking things up. I'll look again and if I find it, I'll post it here for others.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unbind $scope.items on logout. The best way to do this will be to save the unbind function given to your promise in $scope:

```js
var ref = new Firebase('https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/items/[user1id]');
angularFire(ref, $scope, 'items').then(function(unbind) {
  $scope.unbindItems = unbind;
});

$scope.$on('angularFireAuth:logout', function() {
  $scope.unbindItems();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Anant. I tried that as well, but no dice. (Update above)