# Any in depth AngularFire authentication and authorization tutorials?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

There are a number of helpful questions related to AngularFire authentication.

[Basic user authentication with records in AngularFire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481149/basic-user-authentication-with-records-in-angularfire) is a pretty good one for starters.

[Anant Narayanan's presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7ZI7z7qnHU&feature=share&list=TLZ_kcu8bnZmgnxIq8WfjUiaIqGA4z3O31) in combination with the code at  https://github.com/anantn/firetube also has alot of good teaser info.

Reading through the documentation at angularfire.com is um, [AngularFire seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed) is helpful..

Unfortunately, I still get the feeling that I'm wandering through a foreign land with a handful of tourist info-booth maps. Please suggest any direct and complete introductions or tutorials to the land and culture of Angular + Firebase? More specifically, content that connects stuff to authenticated users in some meaningful way.

Comment: How is a question about a software module that connects a front-end framework to a real time data source off topic to stack overflow?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed. It is a good question. I am also have difficulty learning authentication with AngularFire because there are not a lot of good examples out there. Also, the documentation on AngularFire in general is limited :). Thinkster asks for payment now to watch the full tutorial. Did you find anything better lately? I find myself  going to the normal firebase docs, but that confuses me even more at times. Well, guess I have to figure it out by myself...but AngularFire is fantastic if you get the hang of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out angularfire.com for a Quickstart guide, a screencast and more documentation on how angularFireAuth works. There's also a page with the annotated source which will help.

Comment: Wow the real Anant! The annotated source will definitely get reread with extra attention paid to the angularFireAuth service. It isn't exactly the spoonfeeding I was hungry for but I'm sure it will get me past whatever is not clicking yet. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: The annotated source was a big help. I think most of the other vast knowledge gaps relate more with Firebase itself. Thanks again.

Comment: [Thinkster's fantasy football tutorial](http://www.thinkster.io/pick/eHPCs7s87O/angularjs-tutorial-learn-to-rapidly-build-real-time-web-apps-with-firebase) was just posted on angularfire.com. It is pretty thorough.